# Web scraping with CasperJS returns strange error that isn't documented

Tags: module, phantomjs, casperjs, require, fs

I wrote an web scraping script with CasperJS and it works perfectly on Mac OS 10.10.4 with CasperJS version 1.1.0-beta3 and PhantomJS version 1.9.8, but when I put the same script on one of my servers which is Ubuntu 14.04 (running inside Docker container) with the same environment (CasperJS and PhantomJS all the same versions) it suddenly just outputs this:

> I'm `fs` modules

Which is pretty strange. One of my suggestion is that in this script I am also trying to require some other scripts with require like that:

```
var parsingStrategy = require(strategiesPath + strategyName);
```

and the path to those strategies is correct I already checked that. All the other stuff that I'm doing in this script are just normal CasperJS stuff which are documented and work well I think.

Comment: Well, that is pretty strange. Have you installed CasperJS through npm? Does `strategyName` end in ".js" or not? Have you tried the other? Have you looked through the CasperJS source repo to look for that string?

Comment: CasperJS isn't installed through npm, but from the github repo. The  `strategyName` string isn't ending in ".js", but just the name of the strategy module. Maybe it's good idea to look in the repo for this string.

Comment: How can I search in the CasperJS's Github repo for a string?

Comment: I haven't found it in CasperJS. Maybe it comes from PhantomJS.

Comment: Well let's search there then.. :)

Comment: If it will be easier I can show and the other source code, so we can see if there is something else strange.

Comment: Actually I tried to comment these require statements and it still returns the same output.

Comment: So the problem isn't in my code because I also checked some other examples from CasperJS's website. So the problem is with the OS maybe that it is in Docker container or something else.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay guys I have an answer for you - the 'fs' is a module *bundled* with node, so it doesn't have to be installed through npm. The package you downloaded is this:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs
and all it contains is...

```
console.log("I'm `fs` modules");
```

When you did:

```
npm uninstall fs

npm install -g fs
```

The node used its local package - that it shipped with - and ignored the global one entirely. Mystery solved. ;)

Comment: So, we have mr. [alsotang](https://www.npmjs.com/~alsotang) to thank for this. Nice. Now if we could only get the admins of npm to remove this package from the repo, or to add some warning mechanism to NPM when you are about to overwrite built-in packages. Also, look at that [download count](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs): `71.432 downloads in the last month` !!!  Finally there are [more fake packages](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http) out there.

Comment: What? If this library were bundled with node then why are you installing it globally? Wouldn't the need to install the lib indicate its' NOT bundled??

Comment: Thanks ! We have a lot of reports in CasperJS repository? How do they do to be able to merge a console.log() :/

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. My OS is window 7 but I don't think that OS is the problem.

This is what I did and it worked

1. `npm uninstall fs`
2. `npm install -g fs`

I don't know why this happened but it's fixed now.

Comment: I already fixed it somehow, but the truth is that I have no idea how it happened :D

Comment: You should `npm uninstall -g fs` to get the real `fs` back globally. Actually the first line would have fixed it if you had done `npm uninstall --save fs`.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an error, it's a `console.log` message. This module may exist for universal JS purposes (fs doesn't apply to browser so you could remap an import in browser environment to this no-op package with browserify / webpack and not have your code crash). If that is the case, the message should say a bit clearer.

It may also have been published as a stop word for the fs package since it could be a potential exploit if someone were to publish a package with ill intent praying on users accidentally installing and running it instead of the built-in `fs` module.