# nodeJS:fs.write callback and fs.writeFile not working

Tags: node.js, casperjs, fs

I knew nothing about `fs` until I was learning to use casperjs to scrape some content from a website and save them to a file. Following some examples on the web, I write this file `scrape.js` (The json data has been tested so it has nothing to do with the issue):

```
var fs = require('fs');
var url =  "http://w.nycweb.io/index.php?option=com_k2&view=itemlist&id=4&Itemid=209&format=json";
var casper = require('casper').create();

casper.start(url,function(){
  var json = JSON.parse(this.fetchText('pre'));
  var jsonOfItems={},items = json.items;
  items.forEach(function(item){
    jsonOfItems[item.id] = item.introtext.split('\n');
  })
  fs.write('videoLinks.json',JSON.stringify(jsonOfItems),function(err){
    if (err) console.log(err);
    console.log('videoLinks.json saved');
  })
});
casper.run();
```

When I do `casperjs scrape.js` in command line of my Ubuntu 14.04 server, I won't see the file saved message as expected, although the file is properly saved. So this is the first question: why the callback isn't running at all?

Secondly, I also tried `fs.writeFile`, but when I replace `fs.write` with it, the file isn't saved at all, nor is there any error information.

I do notice that in casper documentation it's said that casper is not a node.js module and some module of node.js won't be available, but I doubt it has anything to do with my issues. And I think it worths to mention that previously when I run this script I only get a respond like

> I'm 'fs' module.

I had to follow this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31572054/web-scrapping-with-casperjs-returns-strange-error-that-isnt-documented) to reinstall `fs` module globally to get it working.

Comment: By the way, the way (`var json = JSON.parse(this.fetchText('pre'));`) I get json data with scraping the page feels a little awkward, feel free to comment if you know better way to do this.

Comment: CasperJS has nothing to do with node.js, because it's built upon PhantomJS which has a distinct environment from node.js. There is simply no `fs.writeFile` in the `fs` module which is bundled with PhantomJS: http://phantomjs.org/api/fs/

Answer (score 1):

fs.write expects a file descriptor where you are trying to give it a filename. Try fs.writeFile. https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v4.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback

Edit: Oh you tried that. Are you sure it didn't write it somewhere like the root directory? Tried a full path in there?

And what version of node are you running?